# Matrix and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, self-learning, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> $\quad$The matrix $\mathbf A=\frac19\begin{bmatrix}
> 7   & -2  &  0 \\
> -2  & 6   &  3  \\
> 0   & 2   &  5   \\
> \end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $1$, $\frac23$ and $\frac13$n with the corresponding eigenvectors $ \mathbf v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
> -2                  \\
> 2                    \\
> 1                     \\
> \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
> 2                       \\
> 1                        \\
> 2                         \\
> \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf v_3=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1                           \\
> 2                            \\
> -2                            \\
> \end{bmatrix}$.
>
> $\text{(i)}$ Find the general solution of the equation $\mathbf x_{k+1}=\mathbf{Ax}_k$ if $\mathbf x_0=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1                                  \\
> 11                                  \\
> -2                                   \\
> \end{bmatrix}$.

For this question, does it mean I should find out what $x_k$ is in terms of $A$? 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your matrix $A$ does NOT have these eigenvalues. Replace $3$ by $2$ and it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a HINT: $$x_k = A^k x_0$$

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$A=P^{-1}DP$$

With

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
-2&2&1\\
2&1&2\\
1&2&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2/3&0\\
0&0&1/3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then

$$x_n=A^nx_0= P^{-1}DP \; P^{-1}DP \dots P^{-1}DP =P^{-1}D^nP \,x_0$$

With

$$D^n=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&(2/3)^n&0\\
0&0&(1/3)^n\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

After simplification of the matrix product, and noticing $P^2=9I_3$, thus $P^{-1}=\frac19P$,

$$x_n=\frac1{3^n}\begin{bmatrix}
2^{n+1}-4\cdot3^{n}+3\\
4\cdot3^{n}+2^{n}+6\\
2\cdot\left(3^{n}+2^{n}-3\right)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$